# Upload large image to Imgur (>1mb) through the API with Pyimgur

Tags: python, imgur

Is it possible to upload a large PNG image without it converting to a smaller JPG? I noticed there is an "upload large images" option for imgur accounts, would the API let you use that?

I don't have any experience with APIs so I'm just using pyimgur, and I literally only need the upload capabilities of it.

```
uploadedImage = pyimgur.Imgur( imgurID ).upload_image( imageLocation, title=imageTitle )
```

I have to compare the size of the uploaded image to size of the original image, as the code won't work if it gets converted, and as a rule of thumb it's the 1mb mark.

I'd prefer it not to require an account, as I'd have to specify one in the code, which would then give anyone access to every image ever created through my script, and I also definitely don't want people to have to log in either.

Answer (score 1):

I went back to this when rewriting my old code and managed to figure it out (googled the problem again and found my old question haha). Anonymous users can't upload more than 1MB no matter what, so I just needed to authenticate the user.

Without showing my own client ID and secret, this is how you get the `pyimgur.Imgur` class to act as a logged in user, and a simple example showing uploading images is still the same.

```
import pyimgur, webbrowser
def imgur_log_in():
    client = pyimgur.Imgur(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
    auth_url = client.authorization_url('pin')
    webbrowser.open(auth_url)
    pin = raw_input('Please enter the pin number shown... ')
    print pin
    try:
        client.exchange_pin(pin)
    except requests.HTTPError:
        print 'Error: Invalid pin number'
        return None
    return client

client = imgur_log_in()
im = client.upload_image(path)
webbrowser.open(im.link)
```

The session expires after one hour, though you can use `client.refresh_access_token()` to renew it. It is also possible to pickle and encode `client`, so you don't need to authenticate on the next session either.